# wants to understanding the meaning of these symbols one by one

Tags: command-line, bc

so this simple command:

```
echo "Hello, World! sin($1)=$(echo "s($1)“|bc -l)"
```

I know echo is like print or show, and "" is string , but $1 so my understanding is $ is input and 1 is first input correct? Now, this I don't understand:

```
=$(echo "s($1)“|bc -l)"
```

Answer (score 3):

`bc` is a simple commandline calculator which can read commands from stdin (standard input)
Try: `echo 2+2|bc -l`
s(x) means sin(x) in bc, so when you do `echo "s(4)"|bc -l` it will show the value. 
`echo $(command1) $(command2)` means: run 2 commands then print their output in one line.

Comment: OK  i understanding | is pipe which calls another process which is bc maybe stands for basic calculator ? then -l for like the folder or something ?

Comment: thanks i got the answer  bc is bench calculator but still don't know what -l stand for

Comment: btw -l is the mathlibrary  defines the standard math library . cool now i fully understand how things work .